# Special Characters (e.g., 'Ü') Not Displaying Correctly in Formidable Forms PDFs

Tags: wordpress, formidable

I'm encountering an issue with Formidable Forms PDF generation where special characters, such as 'Ü', are not displaying correctly in the generated PDFs. Despite my efforts, the characters appear as question marks.

I've ensured that character encoding is set to UTF-8 in both Formidable Forms and my WordPress settings. I've also embedded the 'Arial Unicode MS' font in my PDF generation code, known for supporting special characters. I reviewed the data entry process to confirm that special characters are entered correctly and checked the database to ensure data is stored in UTF-8 encoding.

I was expecting that, with UTF-8 character encoding and the 'Arial Unicode MS' font, special characters like 'Ü' would display correctly in the PDFs generated by Formidable Forms.